# Office for Mac Excel app doesn't show thousand separator

Tags: macos, ms-office

I'm using OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2, with Microsoft Office 14.2.4.

**Problem:** Ever since I installed new updates of OS X, Excel can no longer display the thousands separator.

How can I get it back?

Comment: Are you asking how to get it back, or just making the general observation?

Comment: I want to get it back

Comment: The link to your video seems to have gone dead, maybe you can list out the steps to reproduce? I've tried using the same version of Excel, but on 10.7.5 and I can get a thousands separator the normal way, but going to cell format, selecting the number type and checking the box for thousands separator.

Comment: @robmathers reuploaded the video

Comment: As of today May 30,2013, using Excel 2011, and OS X (10.8.3) this solution is NOT working for me. Anyone else? I tried using other regions, custom separators, new files, nothing changes. **No commas**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A temporary workaround is always simply <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to select all cells and clicking this convenient button in the ribbon under the Home tab in the Number section:

[image]

A more permanent solution is as follows:

Go into System Preferences > Language and Text and click the "Region" tab.  If the first region dropdown menu is United States (Computer), this might be your problem.  Looking below shows that this region formats numbers without a thousands separator.

[image]

This appears to be the result, as you stated, of an OS X update. Instead, set the Region to United States (without the Computer part).

[image]

From the Excel Help window:

> #### Display or hide the thousands separator
>
> Select the cells that you want to adjust. On the Home tab, under
> Number, click Display the value of a cell with a thousands separator.
>
> Note: **Excel uses the Mac OS system separator for thousands. You can
> specify a different system separator by *changing the regional settings
> in Mac OS X International system preferences.***

We have just done that, but it appears that Excel continues to ignore the change.  Re-install Office and update us with the results.

Comment: look like you using a different version of excel. mine is 14.2.4

Comment: @runrunforest which screenshot are you referring to? mine is 14.2.5 - can't be too different as they're both from the 2011 suite.

Comment: @runrunforest According to your video, you should have the first screenshot; I saw it in the home tab (it looks like a comma). As for the second and third screenshots, that's in System Preferences under Language and Text.

Comment: I now i understand. it has nothing to do with excel. the region setting is affecting excel. I changed to your suggestion thing is now back to normal.

Comment: @runrunforest glad I could help! no rush- but you still have an active bounty. are you looking for anything else, because I can try to address any more questions you may have (about excel, region prefs, etc)

Comment: Rather than re-installing MS Excel, a reboot then applying the comma format seems to be the extra step to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Formatting palette
Number
Custom
Edit format of the prototype number (I removed the dollar sign, but kept the commas)

I have Mountain Lion and Excel 2008 for mac

Answer (score 0):

Setting the System Region Setting from 'United States (Computer)' to 'United States' worked for me!

Running Mavericks 10.9.5 and Office 14.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just applied the solution recommended, to change the region from US Computer to US, and know what? It worked! But don't forget to close Excel and open it again to see the result.

Comment: Flagging this to be closed as a 'me too' post and not an answer.